# Perl: In search of faster search (through file)

Tags: perl, search

Ok, this is not really a problem I need solved but I'm hoping to use the collective brainpower of stackoverflow to see if there's a faster way of doing what I'm already successfully doing. :)

Here's the thing. I have a text file that actually serves as a database (of sorts). Each line in the file contains name/value pairs which are delimited by "|^|":

```
field1=value1|^|field2=value2|^|field3=value3|^|field4=value4
```

There are tens of thousands of lines. Searching through the "database" is sequential:

```
open( DB, "<file.dat" ) || die( "Can't open file.dat\n" );

# Searching for "John" in field "Name"
my $searchName = "John"
foreach my $rec ( <DB> ) {
  my $value = ($rec =~ /(?:^|\Q|^|\E)Name=(.*?)(?:\Q|^|\E|$)/)[0];
  if( $value =~ /^$searchName$/i ) {
    # Found it!
    last;
  }
}
```

Is this in fact the fastest way to search? Or are there other tricks I'm unaware of?

**Edit:**

Just wanted to add the following observation which surprises me tremendously. When I do this:

```
my $searchName = "John";
foreach my $rec ( <DB> ) {
  if( $rec =~ /(?:^|\Q|^|\E)Name=$searchName(?:\Q|^|\E|$)/ ) {
    # Found it!
    last;
  }
}
```

This is actually pretty darn fast (it takes about 0.1 seconds on a 45,000 record database.

But when I do this:

```
my $searchName = "John";
foreach my $rec ( <DB> ) {
  if( $rec =~ /(?:^|\Q|^|\E)Name=$searchName(?:\Q|^|\E|$)/i ) {
    # Found it!
    last;
  }
}
```

The only difference being the "i" for non case sensitivity in the RegEx, it now all of a sudden takes 20 seconds! That's 200 times slower!

Comment: Put the "database" into a database for faster search results. SQLite is a file-based DB if you don't need or want to manage a full-blown database system (such as MySQL).

Comment: Why don't you search for `Name=$searchName` directly?

Comment: Because I want a non case-sensitive search. I could do uc($value) = uc($searchName) but a benchmark I did showed a regex was faster.

Comment: @stevieb: I had considered an SQLite database but ran into a few problems. Mainly that SQLite does not support (sequential) recordnumbers.

Comment: How many different field names are there in `file.dat` ? Maybe split `file.dat` up into multiple files, one for each field name?

Comment: Make your "database" more database-y: create an index, for each commonly sought field

Comment: Yes, already done that and it works wonders on exact searches but each record holds 70+ fields and I need to be able to search any field so making 70+ indices isn't very practical...

Comment: Case-insensitive searches are expensive because two strings of different length can match. /// And you should use `fc` rather than `uc`,

Answer (score 3):

No need to perform two regex match per line.

```
if ($rec =~ /(?:^|\Q|^|\E)Name=(?i:\Q$searchName\E)(?:\Q|^|\E|$)/)
```

This also avoids capturing.

---

You might benefit from compiling the constant regex outside of the loop.

```
my $re = qr/(?:^|\Q|^|\E)Name=(?i:\Q$searchName\E)(?:\Q|^|\E|$)/;

if ($rec =~ $re)
```

---

You might benefit from loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: The foreach loop through the results of the readline operator already reads the file into memory, of course there are more efficient ways to do so but they won't be split into lines already.

Comment: Right. I meant to avoid splitting into lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the data in a second file so the searches are faster. If you are brave enough, you can use trigrams, saving only the first 3 letters and creating an inverted index. You can do it with all the data in the lines, for example:

```
abc joh mar ant
```

After finding that lines that match in the inverted index, you test the results.
For large mass of data, this can be very fast. I did something like that to find plagiarism in millions of texts, and it was lightening fast.

Answer (score 0):

Well may be following code will fit your 'bill'

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $filename = 'db.dat';
my $name    = 'John';
my $search  = qr/Name=($name)/;
my $record;

open DB, "< $filename"
        or die "Couldn't open $filename";

map { $record = $_ if /$search/ } <DB>;

say "Record: $record"   if defined $record;
say "Found:  $1"        if $record =~ /$search/;
```

Data sample db.dat

```
some=field|^|Name=Alex|^|Last=Starsky
some=other|^|Name=Stas|^|Last=Venichevsky
some=target|^|Name=John|^|Last=Smith
some=waste|^|Name=Bill|^|Last=Gates
some=wheels|^|Name=William|^|Last=Ford
```

Output

```
Record: some=target|^|Name=John|^|Last=Smith

Found:  John
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version with subroutine

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $filename = 'db.dat';
my $name    = 'John';
my $search  = qr/Name=($name)/;
my $record;

open DB, "< $filename"
        or die "Couldn't open $filename";

map { found($_) if /$search/ } <DB>;

sub found {
    my $record = shift;

    chomp $record;

    say "Record: $record";
    say "Found:  $1\n"      if $record =~ /$search/;
}
```

Data sample db.dat

```
some=field|^|Name=Alex|^|Last=Starsky
some=other|^|Name=Stas|^|Last=Venichevsky
some=target|^|Name=John|^|Last=Smith
some=waste|^|Name=Bill|^|Last=Gates
some=wheels|^|Name=William|^|Last=Ford
some=star|^|Name=John|^|Last=Incognito
some=magic|^|Name=David|^|Last=Copperfield
```

Output

```
Record: some=target|^|Name=John|^|Last=Smith
Found:  John

Record: some=star|^|Name=John|^|Last=Incognito
Found:  John
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading the file into memory, using the right regex are steps in the right direction, using parallel processing ( -> https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/MCE/lib/MCE.pod ) is another. You may want to have a look at this perl5 implementation: https://github.com/leendo/hello-world .

It seems to do everything you want.